# A non-hacky way to get the PIDs of all child processes under Linux?

Tags: linux, popen, child-process, pid

I'm faced with this problem: at one point in our code we have 2 child processes that are created by a third-party lib. There's no API to provide the PIDs of said processes in the tird-party lib but we need to retrieve them for later use. There's the option of using popen() with "pgrep -P <parent_PID>" and parse the list of printed PIDs. But that will include the shell process that runs pgrep itself and we need to exclude it. The solution is to use fork() with execlp() but then there's the problem of providing the list of PIDs to the caller (pipes etc) and this gets very hacky for a seemingly basic task. Is there another, cleaner way to get a list of child processes under Linux?

Answer (score 0):

You can read the list of child pids from `/proc/<pid>/task/<tid>/children`, where `<pid>` is your process id, and `<tid>` is *also* your process id in a single threaded application.

This feature was introduced [back in 2012](https://lwn.net/Articles/475688/), so should be generally available.

---

On my Ubuntu 22.04 system:

```
root@ubuntu:~# head -1 /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS"
root@ubuntu:~# uname -r
5.15.0-47-generic
root@ubuntu:~# cat /proc/$$/task/$$/children
1466
```

Comment: Under my Linux version (Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS) the subdirs of /proc/<pid>/task/<pid> are: attr/   cwd/    fd/     fdinfo/ net/    ns/     root/. So no /children subdir.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show the behavior on my ubuntu 22.04 system. There is no `children` subdir; it's a file.

Comment: Some more details: this is doable from C code, e.g. `char filename[32 + 6 * sizeof(long)]; long pid = getpid(); FILE *f; sprintf(filename, "/proc/%ld/task/%ld/children", pid, pid); f = fopen(filename, "r"); ... fscanf(f, "%ld", &pid); ... fclose(f);`.

Comment: Can you use `/proc/self` to avoid the sprintf?

Comment: You would still need the `sprintf` for the `<tid>` part of the path (there's no `self` under `task`).

Comment: Don't do this - see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78187584/265521).

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately no, there is no sane way to do this obviously useful task on Linux.

All the code I have looked at (`pstree`, etc.) simply reads every `/proc/???/stat` file and finds ones with parent IDs that match the current process ID.

@larsks's suggestion of `/proc/<pid>/task/<tid>/children` is no help either because if you actually read [the documentation](/proc/%3Cpid%3E/task/%3Ctid%3E/children) it specifically says NOT to use it:

> `/proc/pid/task/tid/children` (since Linux 3.5)
>
> A space-separated list of child tasks of this task.  Each
> child task is represented by its TID.
>
> This option is intended for use by the checkpoint-restore
> (CRIU) system, and **reliably provides a list of children
> only if all of the child processes are stopped or frozen.**
> It does not work properly if children of the target task
> exit while the file is being read!  Exiting children may
> cause non-exiting children to be omitted from the list.
> **This makes this interface even more unreliable than
> classic PID-based approaches** if the inspected task and its
> children aren't frozen, and **most code should probably not
> use this interface.**

Hard to believe this is the status quo in 2024 but here we are.

You should at least open all the `stat` files directly rather than calling out to another process.